# Reading wrong number of bytes from socket inputstream in android

Tags: android, sockets

I wrote the following code to read some data (specifically a file) received by an Android app through a socket:

```
    DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    byte[] buffX = new byte[30054];
    int k = inputStream.read(buffX,0,30054);
```

I know that the data I am sending from a code written in C is a file with 30054 bytes.

The problem is that the variable k is less than 2000, ie, it does not read all the file that was sent or some part of the file was thrown away. I already checked that the size of the receiver buffer (in the Android app) is more than 80kB.

I tested the same code with a file of size 1662 bytes, and as I expected the variable k is equal to 1662 bytes.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? 
Do I need to close the socket?, which is something I prefer to do when I close the app, not during the code I showed.

ANDROID APP CODE:

```
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public class DisplayNewActivity extends Activity {
        ...
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mainnewact);
            mHandler = new Handler() { // used to show the number of bytes that were read
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    int d2 = (Integer)msg.obj;
                    commentS.setText(Integer.toString(d2));
                }
            }
            ...
            cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread()); // used to start socket connection 
            rThread = new Thread(new RcvThread()); // used to read incoming packages once the socket has been connected
            cThread.start();
        }

        public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                try {
                      ...
                      socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, Integer.parseInt(serverPort));
                      rThread.start();
                      while (connected) { };
                      ...
                } catch (Exception e) { startActivity(intentback);}
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
        public class RcvThread implements Runnable {
            public void run() {
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] imBytes = new byte[31000];
                        int numRead = 0;
                        while ((numRead = inputStream.read(imBytes)) >= 0) {
                            baos.write(imBytes,0,numRead);
                        }
                        byte[] imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        int k = imageInBytes.length;
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.obj = k;
                        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("SocketConnectionv02Activity", "C: ErrorRCVD", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

C CODE:

```
    ...
    #include <sys/sendfile.h>
    ...
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
        socklen_t clilen;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
        int fdfile;
        struct stat stat_buf;
        off_t offset = 0;
        int img2send = 1;
        char buffer[256];
        int closeSocket = 0;
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) {error("ERROR opening socket"); exit(1);}
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        portno = 55000;
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
        if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) { 
            error("ERROR on binding");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        listen(sockfd,1);
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            error("ERROR on accept");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        while (closeSocket == 0) {
            if (img2send == 1) { // interchange the file that is sent through the socket
                 fdfile = open("/home/gachr/Desktop/CamaraTest/fig1bmp.bmp", O_RDONLY); 
                 img2send = 2;
            } else {
                 fdfile = open("/home/gachr/Desktop/CamaraTest/fig2bmp.bmp", O_RDONLY);
                 img2send = 1;
            }
            if (fdfile == -1) {
                 close(sockfd); 
                 close(newsockfd);
                 exit(1);
            } else {
                 fstat(fdfile, &stat_buf);
                 offset = 0;
                 n = sendfile(newsockfd, fdfile, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);
                 if (n == stat_buf.st_size) { printf("Complete transfering file\n"); }
                 close(fdfile);
            }
            sleep(5);
            bzero(buffer,256);
            n = recv(newsockfd,buffer,1,MSG_DONTWAIT); // to close the socket from the Android app, which is working
            if (n > 0) {
                  if (buffer[0] == 48){ closeSocket = 1;}
            }
        }
        close(newsockfd);
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say when you are not there:)
But I would do the following:

1. read progressively fewer bytes at a time and build the complete
   array of bytes from this smaller chunks
2. debug these lines and see exactly when the 'bug' appears

Answer (score 0):

The read method does not read the full stream. it only reads the currently available bytes in the stream buffer.

To read the full data from stream you can either use the [`readFully()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29) or use the following code to read the full data from stream:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];

int numRead = 0;
while ((numRead = inputStream.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
    baos.write(bytes,0,numRead);
}

byte[] fileData = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your code but for some reason that I can't figure out why the code does not leave the while loop. I forgot to mention that code is in a thread (which is also inside another threat). I had had the while loop problem before and I have not been able to find out the reason (it could be because they are inside a thread, but I do not know...)

Comment: Hi, I have posted the updated code. I also tried readFully method but it does not work.

Comment: can you also post your c code? Are you closing the stream after writing the file data?

Comment: I have posted the c code also, and I am not sure that I am closing the stream after writing the file data. Thanks in advance.